# Performing Ajax .Get on accordion expansion only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, get, accordion

I have the following code to do an Ajax .get which then inserts the data into one section of an accordion. Couple of problems though:

1) It performs the .get operation every time you click on the section header to expand. How do I get this to happen only once? I tried experimenting with a boolean variable called `loaded` but that broke the whole thing. Is there a way to perform the .get on the expansion of the relevant accordion section?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#studentQualsH3').click(function(){
    $.get('/srl/quals_ajax.html' , function(data){
        var dataArray = data.split('<!--AJAX DATA -->');
        $('#QualsCheckbox').before(dataArray[1]);
        $('.unitButton').button();
        $('#MainApp').accordion({heightStyle: "content"});
        });
    });
});
```

2) How do I return the accordion state to automatically fit the content that is returned? The line `$('#MainApp').accordion({heightStyle: "content"});` is not doing this.

Thanks for help in advance!

Andy

EDIT:
The HTML into which the jQuery function should insert the data is as follows:

```
  <div id="MainApp">
  <h3 ID="studentQualsH3"><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>Qualifications</h3>
  <div id="StudentQuals">
    <table id="QualsCheckbox">
    <tr><td>Qualifications meet required standard</td><td>
  </div> <!-- End of StudentQuals Div -->
<h3 ID="pStatH3"><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>Personal Statement</h3>
<div id="PersonalStatment">
</div> <!-- End of PersonalStatement Div -->
 <h3 id="refH3"><i class="icon-caret-right"></i>References for Applicant</h3>
 <div id="AppRefs">
  </div> <!-- End of AppRefs Div -->
  </div> <!-- End of MainApp Div -->
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: It would be most helpful if we could see your HTML markup. For instance, what is the main element that you want the response to appear in?

Comment: Also, have a look at this example: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Comment: Thanks @JasonP that appears to solve the first problem at least!

Answer (score 0):

To perform the AJAX routine when that specific accordion section is selected, you'll need to use the [activate event](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate).  However, a better solution might be to perform the `.get()` just once and store the response in a global variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var qualsData;
    $.get('/srl/quals_ajax.html' , function(qualsData){});
    $('#studentQualsH3').accordion({
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
            var dataArray = data.split('qualsData');
            $('#QualsCheckbox').before(dataArray[1]);
            $('.unitButton').button();
        },
        heightStyle: 'content'
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I think maybe because #studentQualsH3 is one of the section headers in the accordion and the actual accordion container is called #MainApp. I have posted the markup for the page above now.